# Integral of the reciprocal of a polynomial squared, $\int_{}^{} \frac{1}{(ax + b)^{2}} \,dx$

Tags: integration, polynomials

How to integrate the reciprocal of a polynomial squared? like
$$\int_{}^{} \frac{1}{(ax + b)^{2}} \,dx$$

Comment: For this specific one, use the substitution $u=ax+b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly as player3236 stated, we can let $u =ax+b$. We then have that $du= adx$. Solving for $dx$ we have that $\frac{du}{a} =dx$ which we can plug into our integral for $dx$. Thus we have $\int \frac{1}{u^2} \frac{du}{a} = \frac{1}{a} \int \frac{1}{u^2}du.$ Can you integrate this function? Hint:$ \frac{1}{u^2} = u^{-2}$